# How to Select MIN value of TOP 50 PERCENT?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am find the 50th percentile of a group of salaries. How can I select the MIN value of the Top 50 percent of a group of data? Here is the syntax I have that fails:

```
SELECT MIN(SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT [PrimaryCompensationBasis-Amount(USD)])
FROM qryEEGroup;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the max salary of the top 50 % of a group of salaries just the max salary?. Anyway, what's the point of your `TOP` if you aren't using `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I need the MIN. Do I need to ORDER BY in order to find the Median?

Comment: Please decide what you are *really* asking and then [edit] your question to reflect that.

Comment: `select top 1 * from (select top 50 percent from table order by  [PrimaryCompensationBasis-Amount(USD)] desc)`?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar that works if you add an outer `ORDER BY`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar What do you mean?, it is selecting one row, and you need that row to be the one with the minimum Amount. Of course you need an `ORDER BY`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar You are correct about the inner query, but that doesn't mean that the outer query gets an automatic ordered result. There's never a natural order on a dataset unless specified explicitely

Comment: @mikeTheLiar No, you absolutely need the inner `ORDER BY` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use nested select statement:

```
SELECT MIN([PrimaryCompensationBasis-Amount(USD))
FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT [PrimaryCompensationBasis-Amount(USD)] FROM qryEEGroup ORDER BY [PrimaryCompensationBasis-Amount(USD)]) tab;
```